# How to decompose $z^8-1$?

Tags: problem-solving

I want to express $z^8-1$ as a product of two linear factors and three quadratic factors, where all coefficients are real and expressed in a non-trigonometric form.

I know that$z^8-1=(z^4-1)(z^4+1)=(z^2-1)(z^2+1)(z^4+1)=(z-1)(z+1)(z^2+1)(z^4+1)$
what should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to write this up as an answer because I find it useful to remember it like this, and it makes the factorisation a lot easier than using complex numbers as Crostul did.

To factorise $z^4 + 1$, we can write $z^4 + 1 = z^4 + 2z^2 + 1 - 2z^2 = (z^2 + 1)^2 - (\sqrt 2 z)^2 = (z^2 + \sqrt 2 z + 1)(z^2 - \sqrt 2 z + 1)$.

This method is neater and avoids complex numbers.

Your final factorisation (with real coefficients) is therefore:

$$z^8 - 1 = (z^4-1)(z^4+1) =(z^2-1)(z^2+1)(z^4+1)=(z-1)(z+1)(z^2+1)(z^2 + \sqrt 2 z + 1)(z^2 - \sqrt 2 z + 1)$$

Answer (score 5):

Well, you have your two linear factor, and one quadratic factor. So it reamains to split $$z^4+1 = (z^2+\sqrt{2}z+1)(z^2-\sqrt{2}z+1)$$ and you are done.

How did I get this factorization? The roots of $z^4+1$ are $\pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}2 (1 \pm i)$ (using trigonometry). Then put together conjugate roots, and you will find the answer.

Comment: More generally, you should memorise the factorisation of A^4 + 4 B^4. It often comes up.